# Floatvalue is always float(0)

Tags: php, floating-point

i want to calculate a shipping-price.

- 1 item costs 2.50 €
- 2-10 items 4,5€
- 10+ items are (number of
  items/10) * 4.5€

My Code:

```
    $item_count = self::getItemCount();
    if($item_count == 1){
        $vsk = 2.5;
    }
    else if($item_count > 1 && $item_count <= 10){
        $vsk = 4.5;
    }
    else{
        $vsk = ceil($item_count/10) * 4.5;
    }
    var_dump($item_count);
    var_dump($vsk);
```

`$item_count` contains the number of items in the cart and gets me the right value. But a vardump of `$vsk` is always `float(0);`

Some examples:

```
string(3) "(1)" float(0)
string(3) "(4)" float(0)
```

Do you see my mistake(s) ?

**EDIT:**

arkascha noticed that getItemCOunt returns a string. 
I cahnge the code to:

```
$item_count = intval(self::getItemCount());
```

now i receive:

```
int(0) float(0)
```

So my Item-Count-method seems to be wrong.

```
public static function getItemCount()
{
    self::$items = session::getArray('cart');
    $amount = 0;
    foreach (self::$items as $i) {
        $amount += $i;
    }
    return ($amount > 0) ? '(' . $amount . ')' : '';
}
```

Comment: If I interpret your output correct, then `$item_count` contains the literal string "(1)". That is _not_ a number, so nothing that can be used to make calculations. You first have to take care to extract the numeric value from it (so "1" instead of "(1)") and second you have to convert it into a number, maybe by using `intval(...)`.

Comment: Better yet, fix the `getItemCount()` method so that it actually returns a count.

Comment: thanks for your answers. I now i get an int val with `$item_count = intval(self::getItemCount());` but float is still 0. like `int(0) float(0)`

Comment: can you show the getItemCount() method..??

Comment: Tanks i got is the brackets :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see too many parenthesis there:

```
string(3) "(1)"
```

If you cast that to `int`, it becomes `0` (it's the string `(1)`, not `1` !), and that fawls all your subsequent calculations.

You need to return just "1", either a string or an int (php is loosely typed, remember), and if you want to be more sure cast that to int().

Eliminate those parenthesis in your `$item_count`, i.e. make `self::getItemCount()` return only the number. If you can't for any reason, just remove it afterwards, something like `$item_count = str_replace(['(',')'], '', self::getItemCount())`, bu the best course of action would be to just return a number